# How to do a GroupJoin based on other predicate than equality?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to do a `GroupJoin` between two collections but based on some other predicate than equality. For example, if I have one collection with items, each containing a range property, I want to correlate each of them with items from another collection having some property with a value in that range.
Can this be accomplished with [GroupJoin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or any other `LINQ` method?
[image: Two collections with resulting groups]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these are your datatypes:

```
public class Range
{
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int End { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

This Linq expression will give you what you want (including overlapping ranges)

```
var ranges = new Range[];
var items = new Item[];

// ...

var rangeGroups = ranges
    .Select(r=> new {Range=r, Items=items.Where(i=> (r.Start <= i.Number) && (i.Number <= r.End))});
```

`rangeGroups` will have `Range` and `Items` for each item.

#### Check out this online demo - https://ideone.com/HQomfc

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `IEqualityComparer<T>`, the best way to modify the grouping logic in `GroupJoin`, only allows the comparison of two `T`'s.

That means you have two options:

1. *Make* them the same type--your range can be a `Tuple<int, int>` with `Item1` being the min and `Item2` being the max, and your values can be the same type, with `Item1` being the value and `Item2` being the...value. Then you can write an equality comparer that handles them. It's pretty darn awful, and I really wouldn't suggest that. But it would work.
2. Implement your own method of `GroupJoin`.

The second approach is pretty straight-forward, as such things go.

This is a quick-and-dirty implementation, with some not-so-pretty complexity rankings. But it should serve as a valid proof of concept.

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TValue>> GroupJoin<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TValue> values, IEnumerable<TKey> keys, Func<TKey, TValue, bool> predicate)
{       
    return values.SelectMany(v => keys, (v, k) => new { v, k })
                 .Where(c => predicate(c.k, c.v))
                 .GroupBy(c => c.k, c => c.v);
}
```

I'm sure there's some black magic to be had here, but in my sample implementation, I'm basically just cross-joining the collections, then grabbing whichever ones match.

There are certainly some optimizations to be had in this, particularly if you're certain that one value will only ever map to one key. And you could probably do something even better if you knew for certain that you were dealing with ints that must fit into ranges, but I get the impression that you're asking generically, so there's a generic answer.

To address your example, then, you'd be looking at something like this:

```
var keys = new Tuple<int, int>[] { Tuple.Create(1, 5), Tuple.Create(5, 10) };

var array = new[] { 3, 4, 7, 9 };

var groups = array.GroupJoin(keys, (a, b) => a.Item1 <= b && a.Item2 > b);
```

Comment: pusing the Where clause into the SelectMany clause feels more natural to me; YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

There is an overload with an `IEqualityComparer<T>` which you can use for this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535047(v=vs.95).aspx

Offcourse, that means `T` has to be a concrete type, which leads to boilerplate heavy code. You'll get something like

```
public class Foo {
  public int min;
  public int max;
}

public class Bar {
  public int value;
}

private class FooBarJoinKey {
  public Foo foo;
  public Bar bar;
}

private class FooBarJoinCondition : IEQualityComparer<FooBarJoinKey> {
  public bool Equals(FooBarJoinKey left, FooBarJoinKey right){
    Foo foo = left.foo ?? right.foo;
    Bar bar = right.bar ?? left.bar;
    return (foo.min <= bar.value &&
           foo.max >= bar.value)

  }

  //If Equals returns true, the HashKeys of both objects *have* to be equal.
  //There is no way to guarantee this other than it being constant
  public int GetHashCode(FooBarJoinKey dummy){ return 0;}
}
```

example use:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foos = ???
IEnumerable<Bar> bars = ???
Func<Foo, IEnumerable<Bar>> resultselector = ???
var comparer = new FooBarJoinCondition();

var grouped = foos.GroupJoin(bars, foo => new FooBarJoinKey(){ foo = foo;}, bar => new FooBarJoinKey() { bar = bar ;}, resultselector, comparer);
```

This is a really terrible solution. It also is, as far as I know, the only way to do this.